# Potential energy of an object that will fall along a circle

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Imagine a tree that stands 100 feet tall. If the tree gets cut at the point parallel to the ground, it will fall over in a specific direction. However, the base of the tree will not move, simply the top will fall over in a circular path before it hits the ground. How would we calculate the potential energy of the top of the tree, assuming that the base of the tree doesn't move, and the tree falls in a perfect 1/4-circle?

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational potential energy of a rigid body is the same as the gravitational potential energy of its center of mass.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

You can divide the tree into small sections, calculate the potential energy change for each section, and add them all up. This becomes an integral in the limit of small sections.

$$\Delta E = \int_{bottom}^{top}\rho (h)g \Delta h \space dh$$

where $\rho$ is the mass per unit length of the tree. (Most trees are thicker at the base.) $\Delta h$ is the change in height of each section from the fall.

Or you can find the center of mass of the tree before and after the fall.

$$\Delta E = Mg \Delta h_{cm}$$

It is possible to prove these give the same answer.